# How to call an async function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, async-await

This is how I'm calling an async function right now:-

```
const onPress = () => {
    setLoading(true)
    getEvents() //async function 
        .then((eventList) => setEvents(eventList))
        .catch((error) => alert(error))
    setLoading(false)
});
```

I believe setLoading(false) executes before the promise is resolved.
Below is the async function called:-

```
const getEvents = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    firebase.firestore().collection('GoodEvents').get()
        .then((snapshot) => {

            let eventList = [];
            snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                eventList.push(Event.fromFirestore(doc))
            })
            resolve(eventList)
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            reject(error)
        })
})
```

How should I resolve the promise instead? I was going to add a .finally() call to the chain, so I could setLoading(false) in there, but I figured I would ask here first.

Comment: Adding setLoading(false) to finally block is good

Comment: _"I was going to add a .finally() call to the chain [...] but I figured I would ask here first"_... asking here should be done after you've tried things out

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it) in `getEvents`!

Comment: "*believe setLoading(false) executes before the promise is resolved*" - uh, yes, it's not in a promise callback

Answer (score 1):

As others have commented: put the `setLoading` in a finally, and get rid of the custom `Promise` - as you don't need it.

With those two changes, it'd be:

```
const onPress = () => {
    setLoading(true)
    getEvents() //async function 
        .then((eventList) => setEvents(eventList))
        .catch((error) => alert(error))
        .finally(() => setLoading(false))
});
```

and

```
const getEvents = () => {
    return firebase.firestore().collection('GoodEvents').get()
        .then((snapshot) => {
            let eventList = [];
            snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                eventList.push(Event.fromFirestore(doc))
            })
            return eventList;
        })
})
```

Or using a `map` operation on the `docs` array of the snapshot:

```
const getEvents = () => {
    return firebase.firestore().collection('GoodEvents').get()
        .then((snapshot) => {
            return snapshot.docs.map((doc) => Event.fromFirestore(doc))
        })
})
```